# Change text color in BootstrapVue table if this column value is greater than another column value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a BootstrapVue table that looks like this;

[image]

I would like to change the text colour of the number in `Age` column to green if `Age` >= `ID` and to red if `Age` < `ID`.

Here is the code in a single HTML file.

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
    <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" bordered>  
    </b-table>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: dataInit,  
})

function dataInit() {  
    
    let init_data = {};
    
    init_data.fields = [
        { key: 'id', label: 'ID'},
        { key: 'age', label: 'Age'},
        { key: 'first', label: 'First Name'},
        { key: 'last', label: 'Last Name'},        
      ];
    init_data.items = [
        { id: 18, first: 'Mike', last: 'Kristensen', age: 16 },
        { id: 40, first: 'Peter', last: 'Madsen', age: 52 },
        { id: 80, first: 'Mads', last: 'Mikkelsen', age: 76 },
        { id: 28, first: 'Mikkel', last: 'Hansen', age: 34 },
      ];
    
    return init_data;
  }
</script>
```

I am using Vue.js v2 and BootstrapVue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve it by using `_cellVariants` property.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        items: [{
          id: 18,
          age: 16,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald'
        },
        {
          id: 40,
          age: 52,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw'
        },
        {
          id: 80,
          age: 76,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson',
        },
        {
          id: 28,
          age: 34,
          first_name: 'Thor',
          last_name: 'MacDonald'
        }]
      }
    }
  })
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <b-table hover :items="items">
    <template v-slot:cell(age)="{ item }">
      <span :class="{ 'text-green': item.age >= item.id, 'text-red': item.age < item.id }">
      {{ item.age }}
      </span>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Upvoted. It's my fault for being unclear. Actually, what I want is to change the colour of the number in the cell, not change the background colour of the cell.

Comment: @user3848207 I updated answer as per the requirement you mentioned in the comment. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have marked your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the same method that's shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71298264/8397974).

Which is to use `tdClass` property in your [field definition](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#field-definition-reference), which accepts a function where you can conditionally return a class or classes. The function gets the following arguments.

- `value`, which will be the raw value for the cell.
- `key`, will be the key from the field.
- `item`, the entire object for each row, which you can use to access other cells values.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    fields: [
      { key: 'last_name' },
      { key: 'first_name' },
      { 
        key: 'age', 
        label: 'Person age',
        tdClass: (value, key, item) => value >= item.id ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'
      }
    ],
    items: [
      { id: 18, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
      { id: 50, age: 11, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
      { id: 87, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
      { id: 66, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
    ]
  })
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is elegant, easy to understand and easy to implement.

Comment: Using tdClass available in BootstrapVue makes things so much simpler and it is making the best use of what's available in BootstrapVue.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply apply class on the row depending upon the condition by using BootstrapVue prop **":tbody-tr-class"** and then call a method on it which check whether age>18 and then return bootstrap danger class which will turn the row into red.

You can follow Row Styling and attributes section on the given link: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table.
You can simply use the code given below:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
    <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields"  bordered>  
    <template #cell(age)="data"> <span v-if="data.item.age>18" class="text-danger">{{ data.item.age }}</span> <span v-else>{{ data.item.age }}</span> </template>
    </b-table>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: dataInit,  
  
})

function dataInit() {  
    
    let init_data = {};
    
    init_data.fields = [
        { key: 'id', label: 'ID'},
        { key: 'age', label: 'Age'},
        { key: 'first', label: 'First Name'},
        { key: 'last', label: 'Last Name'},        
      ];
    init_data.items = [
        { id: 18, first: 'Mike', last: 'Kristensen', age: 16 },
        { id: 40, first: 'Peter', last: 'Madsen', age: 52 },
        { id: 80, first: 'Mads', last: 'Mikkelsen', age: 76 },
        { id: 28, first: 'Mikkel', last: 'Hansen', age: 34 },
      ];
    
    return init_data;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what I really want is the colour of the text inside the cell to change, not the entire row. For example, 52 in the second row of `Age` column should turn green because 52 (Age) > 40 (ID). I upvoted your answer. Interesting that the row colour can be changed this way.

Comment: @user3848207 It's super easy, just add following code in your existing code 
  <!-- A custom formatted footer cell for field 'age' -->
      <template #cell(age)="data">
         
        <span v-if="data.item.age>18" class="text-danger">{{ data.item.age }}</span>
        <span v-else>{{ data.item.age }}</span>
      </template>
Just wrap this into your table as an extra slot for cell text and formatting

Comment: can you modify your answer to do that so that I can choose your answer as the right answer?

Comment: Sure I will update it in a while

Comment: Hi, @user3848207 check the code again, I just updated it

Comment: thank you for the effort but the colors are not right. The question asks for "change the text colour of the number in Age column to green if Age >= ID and to red if Age < ID".